# Detect changes to the Facebook session

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

The look of my site depends heavily on whether the user is logged in via Facebook and resultantly, it is very important for me to detect any changes in the Facebook Session as soon as they occur in order for me to adapt the look of the page to reflect the users login status. I hate using intervals and timeouts for this sort of code as things can get really messy, but it appears to be the only option (to the best of my knowledge).

I have tried using the `FB.subscribe(auth.statusChange)`, but this does not seem to fire regularly enough and necessarily correctly. Maybe I am using it wrong?

**The way I have tested the `FB.subscribe(auth.statusChange)`, is simply logging each time it is fired and intentionally logging in and out of Facebook on another tab. It seems that it takes around 30 minutes for the event to actually fire (and it does not always fire). Not only is this very hard to test as I have to wait 30 mins each time, it seems it does not necessarily fire correctly. Am I using it incorrectly?**

The code I am thinking about using is something like this but I am not to happy with it as it uses timeouts/intervals:

```
window.fbAsyncInit=function(){
    // Initialize the Facebook object
    FB.init({
        appId:"123",
        status:true,
        cookie:true,
        xfbml:true,
        oauth:true
    });
    // Check the Facebook session status every 30 seconds
    setInterval(function(){
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(a){
            // Change the page look based on the facebook status
            fb_welcome(a.status)
        },true)}
    ,30000);
};
```

Alternatively, I would rather use a timeout instead of an interval, but this requires me passing the Facebook object to another function like this:

```
// Check the Facebook session status every 30 seconds
setTimeout(function(){
    // Pass the Facebook object to the welcome function
    fb_welcome(FB);
,30000);
```

Is it a bad idea to pass the FB object to another function outside of the `fbAsyncInit` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually it is better to subscribe to `auth.authResponseChange` event. This is listed on [`Event.subscribe`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/) documentation as best practices.

> For most cases, you will want to subscribe to `auth.authResponseChange` rather than `auth.statusChange`. The response is returned as a javascript array, not encoded as JSON.

**Update:**
Seems like this will not work for you as well, since it's called from time to time if you do calls to Facebook's API and probably in other cases like login/logout.

What you demand is not really exists in Facebook JS-SDK, and intervals seems to be an option. You can set an interval that will only call to `FB.getLoginStatus` and leave the event subscriptions as is since if the status/authResponse changes are detected events will be fired.

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(authResponse){
  // authResponse changed
});

window.setInterval(FB.getLoginStatus, 30000);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! :-) How often does this get fired? Is it fired even if the users status changes to 'not_authorized' or 'unknown'?

Comment: Maybe I am using this wrong, but it has not seemed to work. I have placed it into my code and then logged out of Facebook on another tab. Absolutely no event has been fired on my site and nothing has been logged in the console.

Comment: Is there any point in keeping the event subscriptions, as I will be testing for changes every 30 seconds anyway? I think I will use the second method I suggested that uses a setTimeout, the only issue I have is that I dont know whether or not I should pass the Facebook Object into another function. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: @BenCarey, IMO it's better to keep timeout/interval as temporary workaround in case behavior changes. Anyway from time to time this event may be triggered before code in timeout/interval.

Comment: Okay, thanks Juicy, I am working on it at the mo and it seems to work fine so far. Thanks for your help!

Comment: _“Absolutely no event has been fired on my site and nothing has been logged in the console. ”_ – as the docs state, the result for `FB.getLoginStatus` gets cached, unless you use the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I´m having exactly the same problem.

I´m not a big fan of the 30 s interval since I would have to 
ping my server also to know the status of my user in my site
because I´ve facebook users and regular users and also because
maybe it is not necessary depending on the user action (actions
rely on facebook, others no)

So, I´m aiming to do the getLoginStatus in javascript only when 
the user asks for an action that actually needs to call Facebook
on the server side

I´m using FB Javascript SDK in conjunction with the PHP SDK.

So I think I will do

- in FB.Login : if connected then do server side authentication
  and I set a timeout when the token expires to do a getStatusLogin
  only to refresh the token
- Since the auth.statusChange event seems to fire only on page load
  I will implement the actions depending on the user state in my site at
  this moment (page load).
- When the user asks for an action that needs FB interaction -> getLoginStatus

The only problem I see is that it will slow down user response.
What do you think of my concern about my server load every 30s x num of users ?

**UPDATE**

- Since the most anoying thing was the token expired I will only implement the automatic refresh of the token thank´s to the setTimeout in javascript calling getLoginStatus
- For the rest I will stick to a simpler solution which is a nice server error page on Facebook Exception asking to reconnect if :

  - they have logged out of facebook outside my application ,
  - they have unauthorized my app (so they don´t want to use it anyway).

In my case, those two possibilities are much more anecdotic than the first one (token expiration).
so KISS

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question. Create a new question from this content, please.

Answer (score 1):

A solution applicable to more modern browsers would be to take advantage localStorage events to propagate state change between your browser tabs.

Subscribe to auth.authResponseChange and update localStorage to reflect status:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(authResponse){
  window.localStorage.setItem('fbstatus',authResponse.status)
});
```

Subscribe to localStorage change

```
window.addEventListener('storage', function(storageEvent){
    // this event will be fired in other tabs (not the originating tab)

    var fbStatus = window.localStorage.getItem('fbstatus');

    // take action based on the status

}, false);
```

Note that storageEvent parameter also contains data about the event that can be examined directly instead of always checking the fbstatus value in localstorage on any storage event:

```
storageEvent.key //check if 'fbstatus'
storageEvent.storageArea // the storage object
storageEvent.oldValue
storageEvent.newValue
```